# using setters efficiently

Tags: java, setter

SO, I want to set a number of properties for a bean. I have to set 25 variable values. I know I can write 25 set statement, like bean.setProperty(). I was wondering if there is a more efficient or cleaner way to do this!

Comment: have someone else write them? ;)

Comment: What are they and what do you need to set them to?

Comment: Nope, the way you describe is pretty much idiomatic Java. You could make a constructor for all of them but that would be even less clear IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the names of the property and their names match the setters, you can use reflection.

Here is an example (not tested):

```
public String getSetterName(String property) {
    StringBuilder methodName     = new StringBuilder();
    Character     firstCharacter = Character.toUpperCase(property.charAt(0));

    methodName.append("set").append(firstCharacter).append(property.substring(1));
    return methodName.toString();
}

public void callSetters(Bean bean, String properties[], Object values[]) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < properties.length; idx++) {
        String property   = properties[idx];
        Object value      = values[idx];
        String setterName = getSetterName(property);

        try {
            Method method = Bean.class.getMethod(setterName);
            method.invoke(bean, value);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsmE) {
            // method doesn't exist for the given property, handle...
        } catch (InvocationTargetException itE) {
            // failed to invoke on target, handle...
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iaE) {
            // can't access method, handle...
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes `properties` and `values` have the same length and has a one-to-one mapping from `property` to `value` such that the value at any given index is meant for the property at the same index.

*Note: this assumes that the setters are generated using the standard practice in Java (i.e. a property named `myName` would have a setter named `setMyName`.*

Comment: Is there any advantage to this approach?

Comment: Over just calling the setters? I would imagine only if you have a mechanism in place that would require some sort of mapping of an incoming field to a property in your bean (for example, you receive a HashMap that contains a key-value pair and the mapping of the key to your property needs to be done manually in a configuration file or the like). That is, a translation from a HashMap to your bean (I've had to deal with this case unfortunately :).

Answer (score 0):

If all properties are plain properties, then the most cleaner way would be to use [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

If, however, the object to be created is more complex, one should consider using builder pattern, description of which can be found here:
http://rwhansen.blogspot.com/2007/07/theres-builder-pattern-that-joshua.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse? If so, once you have defined your bean class and all of your class members, just right click on one of the member variables, select Source, and then "Generate Getter and Setters...", click the Select All button, then OK and you're done.

In Java your choices are to 1) make the variables themselves public and then not have a way to restrict their modification through methods, 2) make them protected/private member variables and modifiable only through setter and getter methods, or 3) make them private and only settable through the class constructor.